# Why does Wrath want Ed's limbs?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In the 2003 series, Wrath is the homunculus created from Izumi Curtis' child, who either was stillborn or died shortly after birth. After Ed finds and interacts with him, he realises that Wrath has his leg and arm, and if I'm not mistaken, Wrath talks about wanting the rest of Ed's limbs. Wrath acquires the arm and leg when the brothers attempt human transmutation

Later, after Ed's disappearance into the alternate universe, we also see Wrath fitted with automail that was intended for Ed. According the [wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Wrath_(2003_anime)), this happens after Dante forces the removal of the limbs.

Why did Wrath "need" or "want" the limbs in the first place? If I'm not mistaken:

1. There wasn't any note of the child Wrath was created from having deformities, which suggests that Wrath had his "original" limbs that didn't come from Ed.
2. This suggests that Wrath might have wanted Ed's limbs for some other purpose (e.g. wanting them in themselves, wanting to be able to perform alchemy), but I don't remember if this was explicitly stated anywhere.

Could someone shed any light on this, and perhaps provide an episode I could refer to and rewatch?

Comment: If I recall correctly, he wanted them so that he could perform alchemy. I believe it was stated explicitly, but I've watched the series a few years ago, so my memory may be tricking me.

Comment: @JNat: Yeah that seems likely; if I find a "quick" answer to that effect I'll probably either just delete or post it.

Comment: I've only seen the 2003 series once, but I think Wrath was also jealous of Ed and wanted his limbs so he could become more like him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrath's goal was to be more human, like the other Homunculi. However with Wrath, he wanted to take Ed's life, in other words making everything that Ed owns his own. He already had two limbs that Ed "gave up" so why not take the rest?

I'm quite sure he even says that he wants to take "everything" from Ed during their fight under Liore when Sloth and Wrath appear (where Ed first discovers Sloth is his mother and we find out Wrath's weakness).

This can also be seen during the fight against Sloth in the weapons factory. Wrath takes the box in which Ed stored bone of his mother's and fused it into himself, taking something Ed owned for himself.